# How to debug: "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition"

Tags: reactjs

I am receiving the following warning in my React.js app:

> index.js:2178 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render` or another component's
>   constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved
>   to `componentWillMount`.

[image]

When I click on the link to index.js:2178 all I see is this:
[image]
However, no React.js stack trace is provided. How do I debug this?

Comment: Could you include the component that gives rise to this error? I would guess you are invoking an event handler directly on render, e.g. `onClick={this.handleClick()}` instead of `onClick={this.handleClick}`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! The question I had is how do I even know which component gives this error? It doesn't say in the warning where it's coming from. That's my question.

Comment: @Tholle, what is the proper way to do something like this: onClick={this.handleClick(index)} - so that handleClick will be invoked with an index parameter when user actually clicks?

Comment: The error contains a line number (2178) where you should be able to find the cause of this. Code bundlers such as babel and webpack can be configured to output source maps which makes it possible to trace back the error to specific js / jsx source code files.

Comment: You could create a new inline function `onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event, index)}`, or put the index in a `data-*` attribute `<div data-index={index} onClick={this.handleClick} />` and get it from `event.target.dataset.index` in the handler.

Comment: @HåkenLid can you please provide a complete answer and I will award you the point?

Comment: @etayluz I can't really suggest a very specific answer apart from using source maps. But the specifics on how to enable this varies between build tools. But I think pretty much every cross compiler/bundler/build tool for javascript and css implements source maps, and chrome & firefox etc. also support source maps in the developer tools.